# Is it possible to share a controller between two directives that are isolated?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have this code for a timeframe that shows a *tag* with information on the left and *event* information on the right. Each type of timeline in the timeframe has two directives for the tag/event which use an abstract directive within themselves.

I am adding functionality to collapse the tag/event pair and was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this than passing **collapsed** out of the **abstractTag**'s controller, into a shared controller between **timeline-tag-foo**/**timeline-event-foo** and back down to a duplicate **abstractTimelineCtrl** used by **abstractEvent**.

What I would like to be able to do is share an instance of **abstractTimelineCtrl** between each different pair of **abstractTag** and **abstractEvent** directives. This currently works with just **abstractTag** but I have yet to figure out how to give the corresponding **abstractEvent** the same instance of **abstractTimelineCtrl**. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<ul id="tags">
    <timeline-tag-foo>
        <abstract-tag></abstract-tag>
    </timeline-tag-foo>

    <timeline-tag-bar>
        <abstract-tag></abstract-tag>
    </timeline-tag-bar>
</ul>

<div id="scrollContainer">
    <div id="events">
        <timeline-event-foo>
            <abstract-event></abstract-event>
        </timeline-event-foo>

        <timeline-event-bar>
            <abstract-event></abstract-event>
        </timeline-event-bar>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('abstractTimeline', [])
.directive('abstractTag', [
    function() {
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'abstractTimelineCtrl',
        scope: {
            name: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'abstractTimeline/abstractTag.html',
        transclude: true
    }
])
.directive('abstractEvent', [
    function() {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            width: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'abstractTimeline/abstractEvent.html',
        transclude: true
    }
])
.controller('abstractTimelineCtrl', [
    function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.collapsed = false;
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller isn't a singleton, a new version of the controller is created every time Angular comes across that constructor function. So while you *can* use the same controller in two isolate scope directives, you cannot use the same instance of the same controller.

Services are singletons in AngularJS, so if you need to share data (`$scope`), it's probably best to pass the data around that way rather than relying on the controller.

Without using a service, your best bet is to go ahead and bind isolate scopes to their parent and back to one another, but you might get some unreliable results that way.

Comment: I ended up going with the service fix. Its a wee bit hackish for my usecase but it seems to be doing what I need. Thank you for the suggestions.